# Can I do a stack ggplot in R without adding the stacks?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make a stack bargraph, but I don't want the same group values to sum, I just want them to stack.

For example, if I have this dataset:

```
data <- data.frame(
  col1 = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "D", "D", "D"),
  col2 = c(5, 7, 1, 5, 3, 8, 4, 1, 3),
  col3 = c("grey", "red", "grey", "red", "grey", "grey", "grey", "red", "grey")
)
```

this is the plot I would like to have:

[image]

This is my script that still adds the same col3:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = col1, y = col2, fill = col3)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("grey" = "grey", "red" = "red")) +
  theme_minimal()
```

I hope you can help me. Thank you!!

Comment: Add a group parameter to your `aes()` call (you can also use `scale_fill_identity()` as the fill colors are defined in `col3` plus `geom_col()` is equivalent to `geom_bar(stat = "identity")` - `ggplot(data, aes(x = col1, y = col2, fill = col3, group = 1L)) +  geom_col() + scale_fill_identity() + theme_minimal()`.

Comment: @lotus Care to post as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = col1, y = col2, fill = col3, group = 1L)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  theme_minimal()
```